# Initialise a diagonal matrix in python

Tags: python, list, diagonal

i'd like create in python a matrix with all zeros except for some value selected from a list. For example (very stupid) from

```
l=[0,1,2,3]
```

i'd like create a matrix (a list of list) with the letter "x" in position `l[0] l[1]` etc.. like this:

```
  [x, 0, 0, 0]    
  [0, x, 0, 0]    
  [0, 0, x, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, x]
```

i'd like make it interactive, with a variable length (not always 4) maybe giving on input

Comment: Your l should be a list of index pairs (row and column value). The shown `l` in the question is just very simple. Generalization would require `l` to be a list of row, column values

Comment: Take a look at `numpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want non-zero values to be placed based on the list. So, maybe something like this:

```
val = 'x'
l = [2,1,0,3]
matrix = [[val if i == e else 0 for i in range(len(l))] for e in l]
print(matrix)
```

Output will be like this:

```
[[0, 0, 'x', 0], [0, 'x', 0, 0], ['x', 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 'x']]
```

Comment: perfect...you are the best

Answer (score 1):

You should use numpy's `diag` function.

```
import numpy as np
np.diag(l)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3]])
```

---

With pure python, initialise an empty 2D list and populate the diagonal after.

```
diag = [[0] * len(l) for _ in range(len(l))]
for i, e in enumerate(l):
    diag[i][i] = e

diag
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3]]
```